# Styling the legend in QGIS with line layer

Tags: qgis, labeling, style, print-composer, legend

Working on QGIS 3.4.13.

I have a vector line layer, there are rivers. I put a rule based symbology with two categories and different scale max / min for each category.

I want to put style for the name of each type of river. I configured my legend in vector layer properties (following those steps : https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=l%C3%A9gende#legend-properties)

I also checked this : 
[QGIS styling a legend](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332734/qgis-styling-a-legend)

So at this point I have this in QGIS

[image: qgis]

and that in QGIS composer

[image]

But I would like to have my symbol AND my legend styling apparent, something like this : 
[image]

seen here : [Placing the label style alongside the layer style within the legend - Arcmap 10](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159976/placing-the-label-style-alongside-the-layer-style-within-the-legend-arcmap-10)

I also checked in QGIS 3.10.1, to see if there some more functions, apparently,no.

Any idea?

Comment: I think you've already found the workarounds that are out there. None of them are convenient. The one other suggestion I have is creating a "dummy" feature on your map in each of the layers, that are arranged in a way that looks like you want them in the legend. Then take screenshot and add it to the layout as an image. I know that's a really stupid workaround, but AFAIK there aren't any good solutions. Legends are definitely one of the weak points of QGIS.

Comment: thanks, for the tip, in last case i will do it, but it's in 19 x 3 = 37maps.... ;)

Comment: How are you defining the categories? I just create a rule based styling for a line vector layer and the legend shows the lines type and colors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmb0F.png

Comment: I defined my categories with a a single and specific field, witch have only these two values, no problems with what. In your case, i would like to have "balvanera" in green up to the green line in my legend. Saludos a argentina, tengo el maté cerca mientras mapeando.

Comment: :-) Gracias! Are you defining a Font Maker symbol in each category? Your legend seems like you have already the text and the line, but overlapping.

Comment: I would like to have the same font style for the two categories, i did it already. Yes the text is overlapping the line that's the bad point. There no placement function for the text symbol style in legend layer propreties, I guess is on the road to QGIS development.

Comment: You can define an offset in the font marker styling definition. The legend just try to represent the styling defiinition. Can you provide screenshots of how are you styling the categories?

Comment: I did the categories like this : https://imgur.com/a/UzejTz6

And i want something like this : https://imgur.com/a/bvm8qGS

I didn't find any way to move up the name of the categories